# Show AlertDialog on top of another AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I'm taking some personal details from user in a form which is actually a custom `Alertdialog`. Now when user presses **Submit** button present within the `Alertdialog`, if there is an validation error; I'm trying to display another `Alertdialog` with error message like *Please Enter First Name*.

What is happening is when 2nd `Alertdialog` is being displayed due to a validation error, the main `Alertdialog` (registration form) gets disappeared.

Any reason what might me causing this. Any help appreciated.

### Edit

Please note that I have considered `setError` but I also have some other views like `Spinner`, `RadioButton` in my layout. So just using `setError` for `EditText` is not whole solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If displaying another dialog on the existing dialog is your Application's requirement then, i would recommend you to create a new activity just for displaying that custom alert dialog. 
Add that activity to your Manifest and set the theme to "@android:style/Theme.Dialog".

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="LocationDialog"> </activity>
```

and onClick listener of your Dialog Interface just start the dialog activity for displaying the validation error.

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
         Intent errorDialog = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ErrorDialogActivity.class);
         startActivity(errorDialog);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make the validation before dismissing the dialogue and setErrorText on the edittexts, so it is visible to the user, without leaving the view.

Comment: I have considered `setError` but I also have some other views like `Spinner`, `RadioButton` in my layout. So just using `setError` for `EditText` is not whole solution for my problem.